# Math notation for conditions, branches, ranges, switches

Tags: notation

How to write such logic in a short math notation?

> Tax for the income is 9% for the part that's below €750/month and 11% for part that's above.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Consider making Tax a function of your Income then you can express the tax as a piece-wise function with varying intervals for Income

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piecewise:
$$
t(x)=
\begin{cases}
0.09x &\text{if $x \le 750$}\\
0.09(750)+0.11(x-750) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Shorter:
$$t(x) = 0.09x+0.02\max(x-750,0)$$